# Excel doesn't show graphic

Tags: microsoft-excel

A user opens an excel document, changes something and when saves it under a different name. After now opening it the graphic is missing and instead it shows this symbol: [image: Placeholder] After closing the document and opening it again it nows shows the correct graphic. Why does it show such a placeholder at first?
My only theory right now is that the AntiVirus blocks the graphic for a moment till it got checked and thats why it is using this placeholder at first. Can anyone help me find the cause?
User uses excel 365

Comment: maybe should you try to save the file under different extension, like macro-enabled?

Comment: Wouldn't be the first extension and/or macro problem we had regarding excel. So that could be the problem

Comment: Try CTRL+6 to toggle hide/unhide for all objects on the sheet, in case the graphics are still there, just hidden. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc so with CTRL+6 is just toggles the placeholder graphic.

Comment: Yes. Try it, it might help.